# Run Content Script on tabs opened from background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I have a small project where I have an extension. When I press its icon it opens some tabs using a background script with certain URLs that I will be updating.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)
function buttonClicked (tab){
chrome.tabs.create({
    url:"https://google.com/h",
    active : false
  }, callback)
```

}

Now I need to to run a content script only on those tabs, and I can't figure out how to do so. I have tried multiple things but the script doesn't get executed.

Comment: Have you tried `runtime.sendMessage` and `runtime.onMessage`?

Comment: It automatically injects a content script on tab creation, so you can call a method from a content script which will be called on load. And If you want to run the content script from background.js then you add ```chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
  callback: function,
)```` and send message to content script using tab.sendMessage from background script. And the add message listener to content script chrome.runtime.onMessage and run whatever you want the message received.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if you want to run content script on certain web-pages only than you can use Match Patterns (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/) in **manifest.json** file to run content script on matching URLs only. If that doesn't solve your problem than follow bellow approach:

When you create new tabs using **background script** you should append custom query parameters in the url, for example:

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)
function buttonClicked (tab){
chrome.tabs.create({
    url:"https://google.com/h?customAction=1",
    active : false
  },callback)
```

then in the content script you can identify this query parameter by using **window.location.href** like this:

**content.js**

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('customAction=1') >= 0) {
   // Call custom function from here
   someFunction();
}
```